# Min-width datatable column Primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have a dataTable displayed in full screen. Columns by default seem to adapt their width to the screen width. That's ok.

But when the screen is shorter, I would like to set a min-width to a column of the datatable. In order not to hide my selectonemenu on the column header.

I have tried to set min-width css property to a column but it doesn't work. 
My current work-around is to use javascript to take the current width then if it is smaller than a certain number of px, I set the width to a fixed value.

Is there any clean solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Colums{
min-width: 1000px !important
}
```

I read somewhere that adding '!important' behind css makes it so that it will take that piece of code, over any other min-width of width specification.

Comment: `!important` should be avoided as long as you can. It means your style is not properly overriding PF sheets: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8774997/1199132